# DB2 '?' error in sum query

Tags: sql, db2-zos

I am running a query on a DB2 mainframe via a batch job. The query is submitting but the result is a single row with a `?` in it.

The query looks like:

```
SELECT SUM(table1.column1)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.t1common =
table2.t2common
INNER JOIN
table3
ON table2.table2common =
table3.table3common;
```

This is different from the error message I get when either the system runs out of resource or the SQL is off.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You are having an **implicit** grouping at the first select (`SUM`) while the other results coming for the `INNER JOIN` have not. Are you sure this is what you are asking for?

Comment: What's the result if you do `SELECT * FROM ... `instead?